# How to transition the screens in 4.3 version

Tags: blackberry

Hi all I am developing a eBook app where I need to navigate from one page to next page.I have 20 pages to navigate from left to right and right to left. How can I able to navigate from 1st page to 2nd page.  I search in google for this issue but I am not found any resource related to it. Anybody work with this issue please suggest me with any idea or sample code.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have certain questios & idea

```
1) Do u want to display the content of 1 page of an ebook in 1 screen
if yes u can  go ahead like this:
  a)display content of 1 page on screen
  b)at the bottom or at the top(as per choice) u can add 2 buttons prev & next
  c)clicking on the the buttons fetches the contents and displays on the screen.
2)or Do you want to show the page changing(turns or folds) look as we can 
  see animation in iphone apps.
```

but these are just ideas coz i dont knw much about what u want to do or from where u can fetch the contents etc...
if u could explain more may be u could get more help from knowledgeable people here at stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks Swati for replying..I need to fetch the contents from html and use BrowserField to get it.I am in very hurry how to get the app. We need to take the pages as bitmaps from html using Display.Screenshot().How we can transition the pages from 1 to 20 pages..  I want both page changing effect(like in iPhone apps) for touch screen versions and sliding effect with next and previous buttons for Keypad and Trackwheel versions(4.3 version to 4.6.1).Can you suggest any referrence or code to how to do it.

Comment: Well if this is associated with changing the bitmaps then u can take a bitmapfield and change its resource bitmap when user clicks on previous and next.These bitmap resources must be stored in any vector so that u can easily access its index on prev and next.

Comment: I havent worked with page turning animation in blackberry, so cant guide you abt dat but if i get a link or any source i will definitely let u know.:)

Comment: Thank you very much Swati. I have some issues with the transition of pages and BrowserFields, can we develop page flip effect for Touch Versions(like iPhone apps).Could  you do communication to my mail id sobhannanduri@gmail.com if possible.I have some issues regarding implementing sliding up of pages for keypad versions.Thanks in advance...

Comment: if i get a link and idea about page flipping i will let u know on ur id

Comment: i will be happy if i could help u in achieving this

Comment: How can we modify the font size, themes(background functionality) and alignment of the contents after taking Display.screenshot().Do you have any idea about it.

Comment: Display.screenshot() will fetch an image, i dont think u could modify the font size, but u can do scaling of images

Comment: have  alook at this: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/page-flip-effect/m-p/716307/highlight/true#M138464

Comment: Oh thanx.. I could not found this article earlier..I will go through it and let you know ..thanks...

Comment: Hi Swati I went through it and try to understand it, but I am not sure how to implement these all steps that is mentioned in the article.First of all is this procedure is for creating a Custom class for extending other classes or it is direct procedure for flipping up of pages.What is suspend painting and unsuspend painting here?